# Confusion regarding SNAP Headers

Tags: ethernet

I'm slightly confused about the significance of the SNAP header. Attached is a DTP capture between 2 switches. Could someone elaborate on what 0xaa signifies?

I also notice that CDP/VTP/DTP/PAgP/UDLD frames are all destined to the same MAC address of 01-00-0c-cc-cc-cc. How would the switch know which protocol the frame is intended for. I'm guessing this is where the SNAP header plays in?

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is a reasonable reference for [SNAP frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork_Access_Protocol). I'm not going to reproduce it in detail here but the short answer is that you can treat AA AA 03 roughly as "Vendor specific".

Then anyone who has bought a block of MAC addresses can add the corresponding 3 byte OUI. Then after that there is a two byte protocol ID.

So skating over the business of DSAP, SSAP and unnumbered information, it can be read as:

```
AA AA 03 -> Vendor specific
00 00 0C -> Cisco
20 04    -> DTP
```

Cisco are responsible for maintaining their registry of PIDs. And similarly to hardware MAC addresses, if everyone plays by the rules, OUI+PIDs are globally unique.

Comment: "_if everyone plays by the rules, OUI+PIDs are globally unique._" The IEEE makes it clear that OUIs are globally unique, but the assignment of individual addresses in the OUI is completely up to the OUI owner. MAC addresses need to unique on a LAN, but even that is not an IEEE requirement. Vendors often repeat MAC addresses if they manufacture different network interface LAN types, and sometime in different parts of the world (Wi-Fi is country specific, so a vendor could reuse addresses for different countries because it would be illegal to use the same interface in some countries).

Comment: I don’t think the post is about MAC addresses though? He is talking about OUI + protocol ID for SNAP headers, I.e. 2004 being the PID for Dynamic Trunking Protocol in a SNAP header and as long as the vendor doesn’t duplicate PIDs (and it wouldn’t be in their interest to do so), the OUI + PID is unique and points to the encapsulated protocol, DTP in this case